# Tableau + Station wise total no incident

Tags: tableau-api

I have created one data set for Bus station, Incident type & no incident.

I want to generate a report in a tableau which represent the total no incident occurred at a particular station.

How can I get this result in Tableau?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would recommend that you go through basic tableau learning which is available for free on https://www.tableau.com/learn/training/

If you do that, what I am about to say next will make a lot more sense.

Make sure incident # is discrete, now right-click drag the incident # to rows or columns section and selection count distinct. You can segment it by bus station or incident type depending on what you want to do.

The only scenario this solution would work seemlessly, is when incident # is a unique variable.